# Explanation for why i am not able to import other submodules from another submodule

Tags: python, module, package

```
TESTING
├── aa
│   └── /a.py
├── bb
│   └── /b.py
├
└── app.py
```

even without the `__init__.py` am able to import a.py and b.py from app.py, well the problem starts when am working inside a.py am not able to import b.py, i know i can add the path to the PYTHONPATH but i want to know why even if i add the `__init__.py` inside each folder it still does not work.

```
from bb import b
from Testing.bb import b
from TESTING_PACKAGE.Testing.bb import b
```

Comment: It's `__init__.py` not `init.py`

Comment: sorry, that was what i did @couka

Answer (score 0):

In a.py

```
import sys    

sys.path.append("..")
import TESTING.bb.b
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the system path isn't really a good solution. If your PYTHONPATH points to the parent of the TESTING dir your import will work fine without the path modification. Note that the TESTING and subdirectories all need an __init__.py in them.

Here's the code, ENV, file setup, and running the code...

Contents of a.py

```
try:
   import TESTING.bb.b
   print('import worked!')
except ImportError:
   print('import failed!')
```

ENV

```
> env | grep PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=/Users/briford/tmp
```

Contents of /Users/briford/tmp

```
TESTING
├── __init__.py
├── aa
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── a.py
├── bb
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── b.py
```

Running the code from different places

```
$ cd tmp
$ python TESTING/aa/a.py
import worked!
```

```
$ cd TESTING
$ python aa/a.py
import worked!
```

```
$ cd aa
$ python a.py
import worked!
```

Comment: so i cant be in a subdir and use another module in another subdir right

Comment: @Azucode the example above shows exactly that.. I'm in the aa/ subir and I'm using the module from the bb/ subdir. In fact you can run the code from anywhere. Did you try it?